# run the method in background without launching app when remote notification received

Tags: android

i need the mechanism  in android like silent notification in ios, need to run method in background with out launching the app  when we received the notification, how to do it?

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

       AsyncTaskExample asyncTask=new AsyncTaskExample();
       asyncTask.execute("http://100:5000/api/v1/todos");

   }
```

in foreground it is working, in background not working even included data also in firebaseJson

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately(or fortunately), Android nowadays limits the background behavior deeply, especially with network calls. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

You should probably start a foreground service if you're going to do some long-running tasks or use JobScheduler/WorkManager.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi finally i found it, i background and terminate state also silent notification concept works, instead of sending data from firebase use thired party and send data in data: { } format

Comment: Thanks for help r2rek